# jQuery - Delay the drop down menu

Tags: jquery

Hi
I have 3 menu and one contains 3 sub-menu, when I mouseover the parent of sub-menu, it will expand the div element, however, when I mouseover the sub-menu, the expanded div element can not be held, how can I fix it? thanks

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a class="sub" href="#">Item B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item B1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item B2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item B3</a></li>
                </ul>           
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('#menu > ul > li > a.sub').hover(
        function() {
            $('div#wrap').animate({'height': '200px'});
        },

        function() {
            $('div#wrap').animate({'height': '100px'});
        }
    );  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you bind to the `a` element. If you bind to the `li` element, the mouseover would count for all it's children  (so also including your drop down menu).

Comment: because I want the menu that contains sub-menu to have the "hover()" function